# Getting a 405 Method Not Allowed publishing NuGet to VSTS / ADO

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

I just set up a new ADO (formerly VSTS/VSO) Package Management Feed, and I'm trying to publish a local NuGet package to it from my desktop. I followed the instructions in the feed, but I'm getting a "405 Method Not Allowed" when I try to publish.

I followed the instructions for "NuGet 3.3 + VSTS Credential Provider:"

```
nuget sources add -name "MyPackageFeedName" -source https://ACCOUNT_NAME.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/PACKAGE_FEED_NAME/nuget/v3/index.json

nuget push yourpackage.nupkg -Source https://ACCOUNT_NAME.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/PACKAGE_FEED_NAME/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey VSTS
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer: Make absolutely sure you're using the latest version of NuGet.exe. Run `nuget` without any arguments to see the version.

Turns out an old NuGet version (2.8) crept onto on my PATH from an installation of CScript. Older versions of NuGet might not push properly to v3 sources, so that's why it failed. You can check your PATH using the following commands:

`where nuget` (Command Prompt)

`Get-Command nuget` (PowerShell)

I cleaned up my PATH so it only had the latest version of NuGet.exe. Then, I was able to publish. [This VSTS page on authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/nuget/auth) is also helpful.

If you need to update nuget, you can run `nuget update -self`.

Comment: thank you so much for the help! I nearly went crazy looking for errors, and then when I checked the version it was 2.8... finally it works now

Comment: Thanks for this! I was going crazy.  I simply updated nuget itself: `nuget update -self`. Went from v2.12.0 to v4.3.0.