# Azure publish package to feed getting 405 error

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, npm-publish

I am trying to publish package to company feed that was created for our dev purposes.
Problem is that I am experiencing error  `405 Method Not Allowed - Cannot perform the requested operation because the feed 'XXX@Local' is read-only.`
Steps i did:

```
1. npm init
2. npm install --save packageIWant
3. added .npmrc with configs
4. npm publish
5. error 405
```

In azure i can also see message

```
Release views are read-only and do not support publishing. You currently have the @ view selected for the Local feed.
```

Now I am not sure if i need any new access rights or I need to switch somewhere or to something or maybe some problem in steps i did. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a 405 Method Not Allowed publishing NuGet to VSTS / ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353175/getting-a-405-method-not-allowed-publishing-nuget-to-vsts-ado)

Comment: You can refer to [VSTS Package Feeds Upstream 405 Method Not Allowed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vsts-package-feeds-upstream-405-method-not-allowed/308861)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thanks for answers it seems that i cant publish directly to feed view so i had to remove `@view` now i am getting 403 but thats new story :D thanks for help :)

Comment: [Azure Pipeline - npm install error 403 with Azure Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907290/azure-pipeline-npm-install-error-403-with-azure-feed), [Azure Devops publishing to own feed suddenly results in 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154296/azure-devops-publishing-to-own-feed-suddenly-results-in-403-forbidden) and [Azure Artifacts - Universal Packages - Error: An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023205/azure-artifacts-universal-packages-error-an-unexpected-error-occurred-while)

Comment: Suggest editing the question or asking a new question.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Yeah i will.